# Unable to mix ecto.create, role 'postgres' does not exist

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I tried creating a user called postgres. I reinstalled postgres through `brew`. I'm able to run it with

`postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`

when I run `mix ecto.create`, I still get the error:

```
~/code/blog_phoenix:.mix ecto.create
** (Mix) The database for BlogPhoenix.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist.
~/code/blog_phoenix:.
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question because this is a specific problem specific to the Phoenix framework when starting out.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like your database installation is missing the role `postgres`.

You should try to connect using the default credentials and then execute the SQL statement to create the role and its default database.

In a console run:

```
$ psql
```

then

```
CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;
CREATE DATABASE postgres WITH OWNER postgres;
```